# XEN Server blocked on welcome screen

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, xenapp

I'm installing xenserver on one old computer.  I burned the cd  and launched it. 
Welcome screen appears and i can't press enter to install or f1 or f2 or f3 for different modes...

There are three loadings done : boot/xen.gz,  boot/vmlinuz and install.img.  There are all 'ok'.

Nothing moves, when i`ll press any buttons...

The screen looks like this [Screenshot](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/ANXv2lM86OBTQ7ZZVhV7IznRW6_cLOqHkIldlWAgXqEyfEN7-BJHtkruQ_eNxb49lKQ2Sn9Aub493Ub3HnOZp_-pGmTPDo1PTkg7gE4f7CiA4M0fpfo)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

apparently, this was due to the processor of the computer, it must be a 64 bits

Comment: @aldanux This seems to be the answer.